# JS Simulate button click using hover for x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm trying to simulate a button click in js with mouse hover.. For example I have a calculator component (set  of buttons in a div) in the html. What I am trying to accomplish is when the user moves the mouse pointer over a button and stays there for at least 3 seconds, the button will be "clicked" and if stays there, there will be another delay (not necessarily 3 seconds, could be 2secs or 1sec) and it will be "clicked" again.

I already made the Calculator component complete with click and keypress event handlers but still without the mouse over input handler..

What I have for that though looks something like:

```
  Calculator.mouseoverListener = function(e, calculatorObject){
     setTimeout(function(){
        value = $(e.target).val();
        calculatorObject.handleInput(value); 
     } , 2000); 
  }
```

But this works like:
 (1) Mouse moves over a button (2)Regardless how long it hovers over the button, it will wait 2 secs and simulate the "click"..

Any hint with the approach that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

I'd take the approach of binding event listeners to each of the individual buttons like so (sorry, not tested so might have a bug):

```
var timeoutRef;

button.addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) {
    timeoutRef = setTimeout(function () {
        var newEvent = document.createEvent('UIEvents').initUIEvent('click',true,true,window,1);
        event.target.dispatchEvent(newEvent);
    }, 3000);
});

button.addEventListener('mouseout', function (event) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutRef);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might solve your problem by using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` .. both functions are very similar however `setInterval` executes an action repeatedly every X amount of milliseconds.

The return value of `setInterval` is important as it will allow you to use `clearInterval` later to stop executing a function

```
var hoverInterval = false;

Calculator.mouseoverListener = function(e, calculatorObject){
   if(hoverInterval) {
       // interval already active
       return true;
   }

   hoverInterval = setInterval(function(){
      value = $(e.target).val();
      calculatorObject.handleInput(value); 
   } , 2000); 
}
```

Depending on your code, you would then need to add a listener for your <input> element mouse out event, and when that event happens you clear any previous `hoverInterval`

Assuming your calculator buttons have a 'calculatorButton' class, your code could be something like this

```
$('.calculatorButton').mouseout(function() {
    if(hoverInterval) {
       clearInterval(hoverInterval);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried applying this solution but apparently the hoverInterval in the mouseout event always return an undefined value.

Comment: I tried something calling clearInterval without the "if" part but still the setInterval is still in effect